# Write to registry using P/Invoke

Tags: c#, pinvoke, windows-ce

I need to change a registery value in windowsCE using c# and P/Invoke (RapiDll isn't on there)

I know how to read the key:

```
private static string ReadRegKey(UIntPtr rootKey, string keyPath, string valueName,string value)
    {
        IntPtr hKey = IntPtr.Zero;
        if (RegOpenKeyEx(rootKey, keyPath, 0, KEY_READ, out hKey) == 0)
        {
            uint size = 1024;
            uint type = 0;
            string keyValue = null;
            StringBuilder keyBuffer = new StringBuilder();
            keyBuffer.Append(value);

            if (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, valueName, IntPtr.Zero, ref type, keyBuffer, ref size) == 0)
                keyValue = keyBuffer.ToString();

            RegCloseKey(hKey);

            return (keyValue);
        }

        return (null);  // Return null if the value could not be read
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this? (It's for changing the Device name btw)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RegistryKey reg = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\WJST\WLAN", true); 

// set value of "CDInsert" to 1
reg.SetValue("CDInsert", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);

// get value of "CDInsert"; return 0 if value not found
int value = (int)reg.GetValue("CDInsert", 0);
```

Comment: I've tried this way, it keeps giving me unautorized access. Maybe that's y I need to use the P/Invoke method?

Comment: Oké So I did it this way :) I didn't see the ,true behind the OpenSubKey. I searched for hours why I couldn't change that value.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to use RegistryKey class from Microsoft.Win32 namespace?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: yeah, I don't know why. But the program is not for me. I actually need to change the DeviceName for the machine and I figured out it was only possible in the registery (or not?), so I started with the RegistryKey class. But then he started telling me to use the P/invoke method... which I think it's a lot more work

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to write/read/query registry values which are not inside wow6432 node and if you are using framework less than 4.0 then you need RegistryEX kind of P/Invoke dll's

for e.g you are running a 32 bit app on a 64 bit application,due to virtualization the registry would be under 32 bit node.If you need to create it under 64 bit then you need to use these p/invokes

Hope and wish you succes

Comment: There is no such thing as "64-bit" in Windows CE.